# ImageMagick: convert image from landscape to portrait orientation

Tags: imagemagick

I'm trying to convert an image from landscape to portrait orientation with the command below:

```
convert sample_img.jpg -resize 1670x760 -gravity Center -background white -interlace plane -extent 1670x2288 vertical_img.jpg
```

Unfortunately both `-gravity Center` and `-gravity South` are not suitable for the result that I would like to achieve, is it possible to specify the height in pixel?

Comment: The extent is in pixels as is the resize.  What exactly do you want to do?  Please explain further and perhaps show an input and expected output.

Comment: I need to transform an image from 2000x910 pixel to 1670x760 preserving the aspect ratio, I used "gravity" with "center" or "south" but both aren't suitable, I would like to place the image in a position that's in the middle of what it's obtained with "center" and "south" gravity

Comment: use -geometry +X+Y to add whatever is the amount in Y (and X=0) that you want to shift from south towards north.

Answer (score 0):

I found the `splice` option, using it I was able to obtain an image as desired with:

```
convert sample_img.jpg -resize 1670x760 -extent 1670x1188 -gravity north -splice 0x1100 vertical_img.jpg
```